# Firestore Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following [Firebase's instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) and my functions is as follows:

```
import { DataSource, DataSourceConfig } from "apollo-datasource";
import { KeyValueCache } from "apollo-server-caching";
import firebase from "firebase";
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import "@firebase/firestore";
import { Request } from "apollo-server-env";


export class FirebaseDataSource<TContext = any> extends DataSource {
  context!: TContext;
  db: firebase.firestore.Firestore;

  constructor({
    firebaseConfig,
    serviceAccount,
    databaseURL,
  }: {
    serviceAccount: any;
    firebaseConfig: firebase.app.App;
    databaseURL: string;
  }) {
    super();

    this.context;

    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }

    if (!admin.apps.length) {
      admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
        databaseURL,
      });
    }

    if (!this.db) {
      this.db = firebase.firestore();
    }

  }

  async initialize(config: DataSourceConfig<TContext & { request: Request }>) {
    this.context = config.context;
  }

  async user_updateRestaurantFavorites(data: {
    uid: string;
    someId: string;
    add: boolean;
  }) {
    const collectionRef = this.db.collection("users");
    const documentRef = collectionRef.doc(data.uid);
    let favorites;
    if (data.add) {
      favorites = await documentRef.update({
        favorites: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
          data.someId
        ),
      });
    } else {
      favorites = await documentRef.update({
        favorites: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(
          data.someId
        ),
      });
    }
    return favorites;
  }
}

export default FirebaseDataSource;
```

I dubugged it and I do pass the `uid`, `add`, and `someId` correctly.
`someId` is a string and `add` is a boolean (true)

When I run this, I get:

> Firestore Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in field favorites in document users/XXXXXXX)

I am just running their own function with a simple string.

Below is an image of my firestore showing the user record does indeed have an empty array ready to accept strings

What am I doing wrong?[image]

Comment: Are you executing this code in a Cloud Function (you call `admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion`)?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire, minimal code that causes the problem.  Especially what you did to assign `this.db`.

Comment: @DougStevenson, updated. Mind you I am firing this via Apollo Server

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, yes indeed. Cloud function that runs via my localhost apollo server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up the web client and admin client SDKs.  You can't use the `FieldValue` objects exported by firebase-admin when calling methods exported by firebase.  The error message is coming from the web client SDK, and it's effectively telling you that you passed an object that it doesn't understand (from the Admin SDK).

You should pick one or the other, and completely remove the one you aren't using in order to avoid problems.  If this runs on a backend, you should only use the Firebase Admin SDK, and skip the web client altogether.  If you do this, you will need to assign `this.db` using the admin SDK, probably as `this.db = admin.firestore()`.

Comment: Doug, this is new to me, but makes perfect sense. So you are saying if I am running this function (and others I did not mention) to manage DB entries (CRUD), then I best just use the admin SDK. right? So I should basically not `import firebase from "firebase";` and replace every `firebase.` with `admin.`, and of course set up whatever needs to be set up to initialize the admin correctly. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase can only store primitive types, maps and array of same.  In your case you are saving the result of `admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...)` for the property `favorites`.

My guess is that the result is not returning a supported type.  I have not used `FieldValue` before ... is that the correct way to use the API?

Comment: I believe that arrayUnion produces whatever Firebase needs to store, or it would not have been in their docs. See the link in my original question. Am I not seeing something? I am passing an array to it just like they suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that you need to send exact data which was received by the query. Partial object not allowed

```
db.collection("users").where("name", "==", somename).limit(1).get().then(query => {
                console.log(query);
                const thing = query.docs[0];
                console.log(thing.data());
                let tmp = thing.data();
                tmp.current_game_play = tmp.current_game_play + 1;
                console.log(tmp);
                thing.ref.update(tmp);
            });
```